# What should be asked in 360 feedback from Scrum Team?

Tags: scrum, agile, feedback

We have a Scrum Team with the following roles: developer, tester and product owner.

We want to create a 360 peer feedback form and need a set question-answer format for that. What could be the best set of questions and response choices for this?

A few example questions:

1. Is person punctual in Scrum meetings?
2. Does he/she participate well in Scrum meetings e.g. share new ideas?
3. Is he/she helpful?

Comment: Is the Scrum Master missing?

Comment: It is worrying that you feel the need to establish 360 feedback from *within* a Scrum team. Teams should be very open with each other, particularly at retrospectives and so it would be clear where they all stand. Perhaps it would be better to focus on creating a safe environment where the team members are confident to provide frequent and honest feedback?

Comment: I partially agree on this, it is not worrying per se. I understand retrospective are great tools to bring issues to the surface, on the other hand with a 360feedback you can tackle things more on a personal level, towards single persons. And although transparency is one of the three Scrum pillars, a 360feedback sometimes might be more effective.

Comment: `We have a Scrum Team with the following roles: developer, tester and product owner.`  Then it's not a [Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/) Team.

Comment: It may sound obvious, but will ask anyway - What would you like to achieve with this   feedback? As your question stands, looks like a [X>Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: List-generating questions are off-topic almost everywhere on Stack Exchange. This is an old question, but if it can be edited to be less of an opinion poll it can be reopened by the community.

Answer (score 1):

What is the main target for this survey? As I understood, you want to assess your teammates, but maybe you want to realize how well is a scrum for you?

The target involves what type of questions should you make. But for both reasons I advise below actions:

1. Use the [Likert Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale)
2. Avoid the feelings in questions (well, bad, good or something like this), use the questions-statements in Likert: "This person suggest many ideas how to improve our products on scrum meeting" and then Likert assessment - "Definitely agree", "Definitely disagree" and so on.
3. Don't have more than 10-12 questions

Answer (score 0):

In theory there should not be a preset of standard questions - and I don't get, would you like also a set of predefined answers? - because the feedback should be given in a form of a statement from person A to person B.

The goal is to list a set of information through all the team and be focus on the less positive aspects, trying to get the best out of it. Watch out, level of maturity of a team requires more or less assistance. A new and not mature team can have issues if asked to give also negative feedback and if the balance is broken at the beginning, it is more difficult to fix it.

Why do you need sets of questions-answers and which is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ideal feedback form would consist of your team's standards for "being a good team member" in the form of Y/N questions. I suggest that you take that question to your team directly, either as a form of retrospective or in a separate meeting:

- What are the standards to which each of us should aspire as a team
  member?
- What are examples of team member behavior that you find particularly helpful?
- ...that you think contributes well to the success of the team / increases team velocity?
- What are examples that you find particularly unhelpful?
- ...that you think creates obstacles for the team / slows team velocity?

I might have people submit answers to these questions, & perhaps others that the team suggested, anonymously on slips of paper, then read & discuss. I would do it anonymously in case some of the unhelpful examples were particularly pointed, which could happen.

The end product would be a bullet list of Do's & Don'ts, or some other formulation, that you could then use in 360 feedback.

The strengths of this approach are:
  - it is initially presented in the context of "how do we strive for excellence", rather than anything touchy like constructive feedback
  - it is created transparently by your team
  - it is specific to your team's context

Regarding that last point... it's not like there's an objective, context-invariant answer to the question "what makes a good team member".

It could also be that after such a discussion, and the formulation of a "team member standards of excellence" that was adopted and posted, you might find less need for the 360 feedback to address issues with individuals. :)